# Returns value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, scope

I'd like to create a javascript function that returns an SQLite record value.

But how can I solve the scope?

```js
function LeeSQLite() {
  var valor = "";
  var myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: 'myDB.db',
    location: 'default'
  });
  myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    var SQL = "SELECT desc FROM user_table WHERE id = 1";
    transaction.executeSql(SQL, [], function(tx, results) {
      valor = results.rows.item(0).desc;
    }, null);
  });
  return valor;
}
```

Comment: @PraveshAgrawa: You should be removing messages like "Thanks" from questions... not adding them.

Comment: @squint I think he edited at the same time as I did.

Comment: @mplungjan: Oh, I see. He was squashing your edit. Well that's another matter I guess.